# How to properly type generic function arguments in record values?

Tags: typescript

In the next example `params` argument of `getParamsKey` should get the same type from its `query` field, but it has type `any`.

```js
const getUser = async ({id}: {id: number}) => {}

const getUsers = async ({page = 1, pageSize = 5}) => {}

type QueryInfo<P> = {
  query: (params: P) => any
  getParamsKey: (params: P) => any
}

const addQueries = <T extends Record<keyof T, QueryInfo<any>>>(queries: T) => {}

addQueries({
  getUser: {
    query: getUser,
    getParamsKey: (params) => {}, // Here params is any, should be {id: number}
  },
  getUsers: {
    query: getUsers,
    getParamsKey: (params) => {}, // Here params is any, should be {page: number, pageSize: number}
  },
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygVQggTjAvDAhhATzGBgAoBvASwBMBfALhiusbAFcBbAIw1oEpsAPia0AUKNCRYiFGnQRseQsTLkADrkSKAjABoYGxAGVKALwSKArPyEjxUAmosBFNhgIBJMADMQAHgAFYRxyURgYAEc3dAJGUg10XA4IRgCBLGEAsPgkANxE5IBpBFiyBKSUmDTbXDACUTEJcGg8ampXDEoEBRw-ABUYBAAPKAQwagUAJQRQdGo-AGsSkG8YPv0OmK9fP1qCQQPSKM7uxj704XJG3DbNrogKbJlUDEZQ8PDjmMZnuV1s8IyPIFCDFUrxfIVC4GSHJAD8ADoaDA4XCYAAGfQAeixMAAEhgLOVkjBKAo9voIAALEBsAA21BgPCYNFYnB46DEH25PO5OJgAD04dlaP9AUgXvI3gDItFSr8MBAxR8gbDQSU4sSINCtYjDBZURjsbiCegiWrSeS6pSafTGcz1JoEGzuBh9PqTOYXRyuby-TB+UKRf9+KIgA)

Comment: Your queries actually _aren't_ `(params: P) => P`, because they return _promises_ (currently inferred as `Promise<void>` due to the empty bodies. Even then I don't think the compiler will narrow the whole object based on the sibling properties - you'd be better off with e.g. `satisfies QueryInfo<User>` so it can _check_ rather than _infer_ what you intend.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] this question so that the return type of `query` is `any` or `Promise<void>` so we're not distracted by that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example here you can write `addQueries()`'s call signature so that `queries` is of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`, with the intent that `T` could be inferred from `queries` as an object type whose values `T[K]` are the corresponding type arguments to `QueryInfo<>`:

```
const addQueries = <T extends object>(
  queries: { [K in keyof T]: QueryInfo<T[K]> }
) => { }
```

Then your call works:

```
addQueries({
  getUser: {
    query: getUser,
    getParamsKey: (params) => params?.id ?? 0, 
    //             ^? (parameter) params: { id: number; }
  },
  getUsers: {
    query: getUsers,
    getParamsKey: (params) => params?.page ?? 0,
    //             ^? (parameter) params: { page?: number;  pageSize?: number; }
  },
})
```

The type argument `T` is inferred to be `{ getUser: { id: number }; getUsers: { page?: number; pageSize?: number }}` from the `query` properties of the argument, and thus the `params` callback parameters are appropriately typed.

Do note that the *general* problem, inferring callback parameter types contextually while also inferring generic type arguments in objects, is unsolved and might always remain unsolved.  There has been steady improvement on this front, but issues still exist.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) for the general issue, and [microsoft/TypeScript#53018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018) for a specific issue about code not dissimilar from the example here.  Ultimately some variant of what you're doing might require that you manually annotate your callback parameters, or use some intervening helper function.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygVQggTjAvDAhhATzGBgAoBvGASwBMYBfALhktubAFcBbAIwwYCU2AHwsGAKHGhIsRCjToI2PIWJlKAB1yJlARgA0MLYgDKVAF4JlAVkEix9SVAIarARQ4YCASTAAzEAAeAAVRHHJxGBgAR090AmZSLXRcLghmYKEsUVwwAkj4JGDcFLSAaQQEsmTU9JhM+1z8xylwaDwaGg8MKgQlHECAFRgEAA8oBDAaJRAeACsEYChhUgLYnr7mSgBtMuowGABrSpA-GEGAXWZu+N8Aod2L0Ucs0UoW3E6b3ogKArlUBgtgUout4swAQp9CDClBiqUIBUqkkSrVXkZUWkAPwAOloMCxWJgAAZoVEogB6Cnkmm0mAAPSJKNKSAwQhqaS21Bo7G4fHQAG4JFF6GTYYDFMCaWCqpCMBAxVE5PDakjEhyIOiNbjjFZCSTFTAqXSTYzqpjWeh2Zi6pptAgsbzeBghRjTBYHU7+ULHCLofQBOIgA)

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach, thanks! And what if I need two types? for example result. Should I do something like T[K]['params'] and T[K]['result]?

Comment: I doubt that will work until and unless something like [ms/TS#51612](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51612) is merged.  You could try inferring from multiple type parameters, `T` and `U`, but this is also tricky.  I'm not inclined to delve too deeply into followup questions in a comments section.

Comment: Ok, here is a link to a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77293749/how-to-properly-type-generic-functions-in-record-values