# How to properly type generic functions in record values?

Tags: typescript

In the next example `params` argument of `getParamsKey` has  proper type, taken from `query` field, but result in `mergeResults` is of type `any`.

Expected result: both arguments and result are typed correctly.

```js
type User = {id: number}

const getUser = async ({id}: {id: number}): Promise<User> => ({
  id,
})

const getUsers = async ({page = 1, pageSize = 5}): Promise<User[]> => []

type QueryInfo<P, R> = {
  query: (params: P) => Promise<R>
  mergeResults: (oldResult: R, newResult: R, params: P) => R
}

const makeQueries = <T extends object>(queries: {[K in keyof T]: QueryInfo<T[K], any>}) => queries

const queries = makeQueries({
  getUsers: {
    query: getUsers,

    // PROBLEM results has type `any`, params are properly typed
    mergeResults: (oldResult, newResult, params) => newResult, 
  },
  getUser: {
    query: getUser,

    // PROBLEM results has type `any`, params are properly typed
    mergeResults: (oldResult, newResult, params) => newResult,
  },
})

// PROBLEM queries results have `any` type
queries.getUser.query
queries.getUsers.query
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gSwCYC4oB2ArgLYBGSAvgFDUDGA9gXMFAOYTDxKpQCGcEATpQAFFmyV8E-MXJUAlPgAKiBiUwIAPN0QA%20VAfHUoUHABpqlBbUbNWHLgkRxeAoSPFg%20HXgEZzKG8OAGVMAC9oNABWaxU1DW1dAG0AXQMUAzTaUEgoAEUiJBAASQIAMwYtZUCAJQyMEygARyLEEHxRb0Q%20EjgVBUMoVXVNCC16ppIkDlqIOCIAG2B%20sQZF7DmF5fxawIIIAHctpeBdwO7e1eVBzKhaq1smFigSPgBrCEKkTHneLQAKlAIAAPYAQAjYVwMMgAKwgdGAelErR%2082kyQA0mYCFBPiAGOUoADUvhvu0ypVAVjUoE%20AQQHprENUYhfnAnvYWm12bw3p9yezjKZHLpVugmqZWR12JwxZZTKZpohZvNTqtROtNmrlvsjiddUE%20D0%20rcDAdjjrgIEAPQ2qCIK2uAAWAiguWgAAN6SBPRdjVd%20I6gmpIIhFiB3eAINgmpQFbKnEhpJLucV8KLnAmlTMIAaVp0tfm9ZbttajSa4GbCPqrbb7Y6yy63R6oN6GX6K4HjdAwKGkBGo5BY6Z41YbNQ7Wm2X9G%20qoK6AG5en2eocQais9kAOkzSG30s3PPmu7lzjgB7aICAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solutions

```
type User = {id: number}

const getUser = async ({id}: {id: number}): Promise<User> => ({
  id,
})

const getUsers = async ({page = 1, pageSize = 5}): Promise<User[]> => []

type QueryInfo<P, R> = {
  query: (params: P) => Promise<R>
  mergeResults: (oldResult: R, newResult: R, params: P) => R
}

const makeQueries = <T, Q>(queries: {[K in keyof (T&Q)]: K extends (keyof (T | Q)) ? QueryInfo<T[K], Q[K]> : never}) => queries

const queries = makeQueries({
  getUsers: {
    query: getUsers,
    mergeResults: (oldResult, newResult, params) => newResult,
  },
  getUser: {
    query: getUser,
    mergeResults: (oldResult, newResult, params) => newResult,
  },
})


queries.getUser.query
queries.getUsers.query
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gSwCYC4oB2ArgLYBGSAvgFDUDGA9gXMFAOYTDxKpQCGcEATpQAFFmyV8E-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)

Comment: Wow, I was already thinking it is impossible. My respect! I wonder how did you get that :)

Comment: Even if the provided code solves the problem, it is always better add supporting information to explain why and how this works (especially if no comment are visible in the code block).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and type inference::

```js
type MakeQueries = <Queries extends Record<string, QueryInfo<any, any>>>(queries: Queries) => { /* ... */ };
```

The `makeQueries` function now uses a generic type parameter `Queries` which extends a record of `QueryInfo` objects. That allows `makeQueries` to work with any record of queries, not just a specific set of queries.

The usage remains largely the same, but the `makeQueries` function can now be utilized with different query structures, as long as they conform to the `QueryInfo` type.

```js
type User = { id: number };

const getUser = async ({ id }: { id: number }): Promise<User> => ({ id });

const getUsers = async ({ page = 1, pageSize = 5 }): Promise<User[]> => [];

type QueryInfo<Params, Result> = {
    query: (params: Params) => Promise<Result>;
    mergeResults: (oldResult: Result, newResult: Result, params: Params) => Result;
};

type MakeQueries = <Queries extends Record<string, QueryInfo<any, any>>>(queries: Queries) => {
    [K in keyof Queries]: {
        query: Queries[K]['query'];
        mergeResults: (
            oldResult: ReturnType<Queries[K]['query']> extends Promise<infer Result> ? Result : never,
            newResult: ReturnType<Queries[K]['query']> extends Promise<infer Result> ? Result : never,
            params: Parameters<Queries[K]['query']>[0]
        ) => ReturnType<Queries[K]['query']> extends Promise<infer Result> ? Result : never;
    }
};

const makeQueries: MakeQueries = (queries) => queries;

const queries = makeQueries({
    getUsers: {
        query: getUsers,
        mergeResults: (oldResult, newResult, params) => newResult,
    },
    getUser: {
        query: getUser,
        mergeResults: (oldResult, newResult, params) => newResult,
    },
});

// Usage
(async () => {
    const userResult = await queries.getUser.query({ id: 1 });
    const usersResult = await queries.getUsers.query({ page: 1, pageSize: 5 });
    console.log(userResult, usersResult);
})();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3lAlgEwFxQB2ArgLYBGSUAvgNwBQ9AxgPaFzBQDmEw8VaAIZwQhJlAAUmXDQLT8RMpWTUAlAQAKiFqSwIAPP0QA+VKanYcNVQ2ZsO3Xkbioow0eIthBPVwEYAGihvHgBlLAAvaDQAVmtNbV0DIwBtAF1TFFN021BIKABFYiQQAElCADMWfQ1BREFSOCCAJQg4YgAbYEyMeih+qABHYsQQAglvesbNOoa4VTMoLR09CH1W9q7jBgGoUiQeDc7gOHGWDpwjroIr4CDCCAB3W5u246DJuZmp+cXbhjojDy0AAsoIANYQIpILBtVz6aGIWEuCAAD2AEEIOBcrVYiBw+g4SMIXCCiLKlWqgkIICC1JAxkZEmGMLaBERyIWWV6uxSAGlsIQoJCQCwKoURsi0nI+rsBizRuzJW1+WkUgByBUgdVpHZy-r7RCHN5dU6SWX63bnS4m4CvYDERCEAAq4DWHJVfLVmpG2oyUDRGKxLmWSTWWEqVFupgA-FBblACA8AG5IAIWy39B7PW32x0ut0I5VwVUarU60yBzHYpaJVb6CMVKO22Px22JogQVOIdOZ3afaZLWb7DGIOBF1klr1l30VlIABjSGd2XNMrQdTtdkAnSM93vL-qrwdrKwMjebm26UDjCaTXaQev61HogLs7E4pAhUOLBDBkI9LhoMyxarkMxa2Kw75gZOrifv+xZSBmPB8AgY4ypmWoEMhzi9pahrGpeZoSNatz3E8pHBMOvzctmpEZtQuH9NhqHoZamGOChabLgM+EQLcREkbaZE5peHxUaBtFCfR6ZqLYAD0cmwHAPgQPQEjuGIkigegGaQQ4xCoQmQiPIIWCcAqyIAHTMUgllahYuAEH41iPlAemcAZSBwEZbgmWZ0G7nA1lOKhQX2ZgIQQE5YlhJEUVQHEsm6fY5wQJZHQsFwEieYgFE5d5to2C+qgSEVQA)

Comment: Your answer has a lot of duplication and no inferring of types, and function makeQueries knows about what arguments it will receive beforehand, which is ridiculous. So you can't even move it to another reusable package.

Also, it is flooded with unnecessary information.

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov Thank you for your feedback. I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: I checked it in playground, mergeResults functions arguments have type any, worse than in my original code. Also, you may remove enforceType, types are easily visible in playground.

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov Got it. I have revised the answer. At least, I do not see any `any` with that last version.

Comment: Are you using AI? Answer is still incorrect. Won't waste more of my time, sorry.

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov No, and considering the time I spent on this, I don't know if typescript supports what you are asking for. I hope your bounty will attract a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using a separate utility function `makeQuery` that helps infer the inner object I don't think it's possible (or it's possible but you will face some limitations like `ReturnType` will not be inferred)

The utility function `makeQuery` will help you connect `query` and `mergeResults` so that return type will be used as well:

```
const makeQuery = <P, R>(query: QueryInfo<P, R>) => query;
```

TypeScript Playground - https://tsplay.dev/NDVD4W

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in your example makeQueries which takes a record is gone, but the question was about passing query infos as values in a record.

Comment: If it’s not possible to do it with makeQueries function, you don’t need this function, this is why I removed it

Comment: I correct myself: it's possible, but I couldn't find my approach working, please have a look at Akimov Vladimir's solution or replace P and R with F (=(...P) => R) and it would work as well

Answer (score -1):

The `any` in the query results comes from the `any` in the type of `makeQueries`.

Moving the any to the right side of an `extends` would allow it to be overridden with the precise return type of the queries. For example:

```js
const makeQueries = <
  Q extends Record<string, QueryInfo<never, any>>
>(queries: Q) => queries
```

Comment: I checked your answer in playground, it doesn't work. And type for params even became worse - `never`.